# Multiple VBA targets for data validation on a single sheet

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu

There are similar posts relating to my question, but I have struggled to adapt them to my problem. I currently have the following code which works just fine:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set Target = Range("B4")

    If Target.Value = "Yes" Then
    
        Call DropDownListOn
    
    Else
        
        Call DropDownListOff
    
    End If
    
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

and the macros that are being called are:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DropDownListOn()
    
    Sheet1.Activate
    
    Sheet1.Range("A5").Value = "Plot default probability"
    Sheet1.Range("B5").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="Yes, No"
    
End Sub
```

and

```
Option Explicit

Sub DropDownListOff()
    
    Sheet1.Range("A5").Value = ""
    Sheet1.Range("B5").Validation.Delete
    
End Sub
```

Essentially what it does is as follows: Cell B4 is dropdown list. If "Yes" is chosen, then by calling the macro "DropDownListOn", it generates a new dropdown list in cell B5. This part works just fine; but, say, that once the dropdown list in cell B5 appears, I want to call another macro **if B5 is chosen to be "Yes"** (e.g., generating another dropdown list in cell B6). Given that only one target can be assigned to each sheet, this does not seem to be very straightforward. There seem to be suggestions for ways around this obstacle on Stackoverflow, but I struggle to adopt these to my own case. Any help and/or sample code will very much be appreciated.

Comment: Your approach looks strange to me... 1. I have some doubts that you nee that event to be triggered **for any change in the sheet** cells. So you should use **Target, and figure the code to be triggered only when "B4" cell is changed**. 2. Using `Application.EnableEvents = False` without being followed by `Application.EnableEvents = True`, at the code end, will make the event **working only one time**. Next time, the event will not be triggered any more, events not being enabled... If you will show us the two used Subs/Functions, I will show you how to make a workable code...

Comment: @FaneDuru Your 2nd point is valid and I had erroneously deleted the Application.EnableEvents=True when transferring the code to StackOverFlow. Note that the following code works ok, and it calls a new dropdown list as intended in cell B5. But How can I extend this as described in the question? Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure that you really want what your code tries doing... Firstly, you cannot delete all `chartObects` at once, as you try in your first `Sub`. The, you were talking about **creating a new drop-down in  "B6", which does not exist in the code you show**...

Comment: @FaneDuru creating a new dropdown in B6 does not exist because I am not sure how, since the dropdown in B6 is only supposed to get generated, if and only if the new dropdown in B5 is assigned "Yes". Sorry if I have not been clear in posing the question. I will make the modifications necessary to articulate the questions properly. As for the charts, that can be ignored for now (I will remove that from the sample code)

Comment: Please, test the adapted event I posted and take care to delete charts ONE BY ONE, and add the code able to create the validation in "B6"... But, don't you also need to clear the validation of "B6" when you delete the one in "B5"? Like logical approach, I mean...

Comment: @FaneDuru The code works just fine, thank you! However, despite it being functional, I am getting a run-time 1004 error (when I press debug, it points at this line {Sheet1.Range("B5").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="Yes, No"} in the first macro. Do you know what may be causing this?

Comment: @FaneDuru ah nevermind! Mistake from my end! Thank you for the immense help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next updated event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Target.Address(0, 0) = "B4" Then
    If Target.Value = "Yes" Then
        Call DropDownListOn 'it let it creating the drop-down in "B5", TRIGGERING the change event
                            'but delete the charts   ONE BY ONE!
    Else
        Application.EnableEvents = False
           Call DropDownListOff 'the event is not triggered here.
           'if you want to also clear "B6", you should place such a code line in the above Sub...
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
 ElseIf Target.Address(0, 0) = "B5" Then
     Application.EnableEvents = False
        'Place here the sub able to create the drop-down validation in "B6"
        'it let it creating something else, but without triggering the event
    Application.EnableEvents = Trud
 End If
End Sub
```